# LinqPad Syntax for deleting foreign key constraint on .SDF file

Tags: foreign-keys, linqpad, sdf

I tried to delete a foreign key constraint with LINQPad but I don't know ho to do that in LINQPad.

What would be the exact syntax for a table named "SalesOrderDetail" and a key "FK_dbo.SalesOrderDetail_dbo.SalesOrderDetail_ParentSalesOrderDetailId".

It's an SDF datebase file. Provider is Microsoft SQL Compact Server.

LinqPad is 5.x and 7.x

Thank you

FZ

Comment: What LINQ are you using: LINQ to SQL / EF 6.x / EF Core 2.0 / 2.1 / 3.x / 5.x / 6.x? What database provider?

Comment: Add some informations.

Comment: Doesn't `ALTER TABLE SalesOrderDetail DROP CONSTRAINT FK_dbo.SalesOrderDetail_dbo.SalesOrderDetail_ParentSalesOrderDetailId
` work? (It is a long time since I used the Compact edition, but I don't think the syntax for this is any different from how you do it in the normal MS SqlServer 
editions)